# How to dynamically change value from drop-down list with simple javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, drop-down-menu, checkbox, onchange

I have a form consists of check-box and drop-down list.
And I would like to display total amount in label format based from above action capture from client-side.

```
<?php
if ($AccountStatus == 'VIP')
{
?>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="events" value="seminar01" />
   A) Seminar 01
  </td>
  <td>
   01 pax
  </td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
?>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" name="events" value="seminar02" />
   B) Seminar 02
  </td>
  <td>
   <select name="events_dinner" onchange="copy();">
    <option value="01" selected="selected">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
   </select>
   &nbsp;pax
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Total to pay: SGD <div id="label"></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Now I do not know how to write a proper Javascript in order to display my Total Amount in label.

1st, php script check the customer is VIP or normal.
2nd, if customer is VIP, then display another row, else only one row.
3rd, each row has a check-box
4th, [seminar01] checkbox if checked, then database done by php script will keep record, label has nothing to display.
5th, if [seminar02] checkbox had been checked, the label only activate and display value [20] for [01] selected in drop-down list, or value [40] displayed for [02] selected in drop-down list.
6th, database again recorded down from php script.

What I concern is the Label part as how to display the value with javascript and from my check-box and drop-down list triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeValue(){
     var select=document.getElementById('myselectbox_id');
     var index = 0;
     select.options[index].value = 'newvalue';
     select.options[index].text = 'newtext';
}
```

Change index value 0 in example to meet your goal. More info [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml)